show that $1x=x ;\forall x \in F^n$
show that $1x=x ;\forall x \in F^n$
so I have $1(x_1,x_2....x_n)$
or $(1x_1,1x_2.....1x_n)$
now what?
source :- Axler , linear algebra done right 4e

$1x_i=x_i$ in $\mathbb F$, right?

Here $\mathbb{F}$ stands for either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, so $$1x_i=x_i, \forall i$$
Also, in a field, $1$ stands for multiplicative identity, so the equality holds.

Chapter 1.A 1.6Notation

I thought I had to prove that, so that's an axiom?

@mathandphysicsforever You have to prove that $1x=x$ for $x\in \mathbb F^n$. The fact that $1x=x$ for $x\in \mathbb F$ is an axiom of $\mathbb F$.

Since in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, we know that $1$ is the multiplicative identity, everything times $1$ will get the same.
